# zend loading models using eval in helpers

Tags: zend-framework

i want to load models from helpers...  im using eval to insert the modelname etc.

```
 public function getMod($mName) {
     // this works but need a dynamic one
$model = $this->users = new Application_Model_Users();  

// so i did this:

         $model = $this->_listsMod = eval ("new Application_Model_$mName();");



        return $model;
```

and you can call it by: `$this->_helper->getmod->getMod('Users')->myuserFunc();`

but it doesnt work, its says Fatal error: Call to a member function myuserFunc() on a non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Have you tried:

```
    $modelName = 'Application_Model_'.$mName;
    $model = $this->_lists = new $modelName ;
```

?

You should have a look at the Factory Pattern (which is effectively what you're doing here) eg [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

As you probably know, its best to avoid using `eval` if possible.  Also, it seems a bit odd needing to load Models like this - can you tell us why you need to load them like this?

*Note: I've updated this answer following comments below, to make it quicker for future readers of the question / answer.*

Comment: nope, doesnt work..   $model = new 'Application_Model_'.$mName.'()';   doesnt either.

Comment: What is the error message?  Have you tried doing something like `$model = new 'Application_Model_'.'Users';` in an `Action`?

Comment: nope.  error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: Ahh, sorry, this should work `$modelName = 'Application_Model_'.$mName; $model = new $modelName;`